BertTokenizer.from_pretrained raises UnicodeDecodeError
I pre-trained a pytorch_model.bin from a pre-train script. Yet when I load it with the following codes, it raises UnicodeDecodeError. Codes are as follows:
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("/path/to/pytorch_model.bin") # Raise UnicodeDecodeError

The traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jupyter-raptor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1811, in from_pretrained
    return cls._from_pretrained(
  File "/home/jupyter-raptor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1965, in _from_pretrained
    tokenizer = cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)
  File "/home/jupyter-raptor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.vocab = load_vocab(vocab_file)
  File "/home/jupyter-raptor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/tokenization_bert.py", line 121, in load_vocab
    tokens = reader.readlines()
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 64: invalid start byte

How can I resolve this issue?
Versions:

transformers 4.28.1
tokenizers 0.13.3
Python 3.10.10


from_pretrained take as input the path to the directory containing model weights saved using save_pretrained() not the bin file .
You can save your model:
model.save_pretrained("my_model_directory")

Then You can load it :
BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("my_model_directory")


Thanks. I know this normal practice, but the script run_gen.py in https://github.com/fastnlp/CPT/tree/master/finetune/generation asks for pytorch_model.bin.

That how it work ! there is some other options , but None of them include the pytorch_model.binas input.
I do not see where the script asked for it, can you tell me what line?

Thanks for your reply. The README is somehow misleading. After I added the files generated by the tokenizer to the file, and load the folder using the from_pretrained() function, the function works fine now. The UnicodeDecodeError is also misleading as well.
